# Postman pre-request script: request vs pm.request

Tags: javascript, postman

Postman pre-request scripts seem to have both `request` and `pm.request` variables available. They seem to be different types. What's the difference between these / for what purposes should each be used?

The context is writing a pre-request script for Hawk authentication https://gist.github.com/michalc/b3f03e9234a2916810af12fa1d6c44af (to extend it a bit beyond Postman's built-in one / work around a suspected bug)

Comment: The `pm.*` API is the newer way (It's been around for a while now) of getting and setting data within the sandbox. For future proofing your request scripts, I would always go for the `pm.*` option. Without more context about how you might be using `request` is difficult to provide any input on that.

Comment: @DannyDainton I've added a bit more context

Comment: If you feel something is a bug, feel free to raise it on the Issue Tracker - Could possibly be something around that already. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues